# Where is the console ST2/GDB

Tags: console, sublime-text-2, c++, gdb, sublime-text

I'm using sublime text 2. I got GDB to work but I don't see a console window anywhere. I see the GDB console but nothing that outputs text from my C++ program.

How do I use GDB and see my the console app text?

Comment: i'm guessing view..show console isn't what you want?

Comment: @barlop: Not unless `printf("Hello World\n")` shows up there and it doesn't